# Ignore undefined values in the find method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have a service function that should return users based on condition, when it's present, or return just all records from collection:

```
function getUsers(status: string[]) {
  return this.usersModel.find({ status });
}
```

But when users don't submit anything in params, the status will be undefined and mongo will search for users with `status: undefined`. Can I make the mongoose `find` function ignore status if it's undefined and do not include it in the query?

NOTE: I don't want to explicitly construct the query in the service, as it's violating the service scope of responsibility.

Comment: Can you not just include a condition that if status is a falsy value just return an empty array?
`function getUsers(status: string[]) {
  if (status) return this.usersModel.find({ status });
  return [];
}`

Comment: Empty array means exclude status from condition and return all values from collection in this case

Comment: then you can do something like this:-
`function getUsers(status: string[]) {   if (status) return this.usersModel.find({ status });   return this.userModel.findAll(); }`

Comment: We can also include the condition in query iteself:-
`this.usersModel.find({"status": {$ne: null}});`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something here, but is there anything stopping you from simply running a different query (one absent of such conditions) if status is empty?

It is afterall a service function, business logic isn't the end of the world :)

Comment: yes, but I don't think that it's a good idea to put it into the service, also not enough business logic to make a repository. Can you suggest another way of doing so?